# The usability of Unique Constraint

Tags: sql, constraints, unique

I would like to ask in which cases its proper to use UNIQUE keyword in SQL. I know that if I declare a column as a primary key has uniqueness on its own but what happens with other attributes like country? Is it proper to use a unique constraint there?

Comment: It will certify that no duplicat **exact** values are entered to your field. Nulls beheviour may be implementation specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unique` keyword in sql is used whenever you want each and every row entry of that column to be different from each other. A primary key column is automatically unique but there are some cases in which you may want more columns to be unique.

For example if you have a `product_id` as primary key it will ensure that no other row will have a product with `product_id` as that row. And in addition to that, you want that no two rows should have the same `product_imei`, then you can make the `product_imei` unique.

You can make a composite primary key like `Primary Key(column1,column2)` but that will mean that the combination you get from `product_id` and `product_imei` will be unique.

For example
`(DLK-22,356938035643809)` and `(DLK-22, 11111111111111)` both can exist in a table if `(product_id,product_imei)` is the primary key.

So you can use a `unique` constraint on as much columns as you like and its need depends on the scenario of the problem you are facing. You can use the `unique` constraint with the `country` if that helps you, there is no problem in doing so

Answer (score 1):

The UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are different. Both the UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns. A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Besides, a primary key column is NOT NULL, while the UNIQUE constraint doesn't prohibit null values.

Answer (score 0):

As any other constraint the `UNIQUE` constraint enforces some level of **data quality**. If you add this constraint to a column, then all values on that column will be different.

For example, on a table where `EMPLOYEE_PK` is already unique (because it's the PK) you may want to enforce the `CARD_NUMBER` column is also unique; that's the number displayed on the employee card. In your model the card number may be different from the PK, and you may also need to make sure it's unique.

Another extra benefit of a UNIQUE constraint is that other tables can link foreign keys to it. Since a UNIQUE column effectively acts as a "table key", any other table can establish a foreign key pointing to it. I've met many people who [wrongly] think that foreign keys can only point to primary keys.

Comment: in case there is already a PK in the table can the UNIQUE collumn act again as a table key?

Comment: A table can have multiple candidate keys. Only one of them is chosen as the primary key, though.